# changing the names of network interfaces, debian wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, networking, ethernet, network-interface

I'm trying to set a name for an interface, "ethLan" instead of eth0. Doing so also ensures that the if's name will remain consistent at every reboot and kernel.

I did find some articles in the subject, but they are all a couple of years old:
http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/463
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/nameif.txt

I did as they said and added the **ethLan mac** to **/etc/mactabs/**.
At this point I have two problems:
1) The `if [...] && /sbin/nameif` script I put at **/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/** does not run. I solved this by adding this to the */etc/init.d/networking*, but why doesn't *if-pre-up.d* work?
2) The interface won't load unless I manually do **ifconfig ethLan up**, in spite of adding it to */etc/network/interfaces*. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18):

The articles you found are somewhat outdated. There is now an easy method to assign names to network interfaces, through [Udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev).

On Debian and derivatives (including Ubuntu), look out for a file called `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. This file is created by `/lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules` with the help of the script `/lib/udev/write_net_rules`. Each time udev sees a new network device, it will assign it a new number and append that number to `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. That way, interface numbers are persistent across reboots, and will persist after a reinstallation if you restore `/etc`.

(If your distribution doesn't ship these files, look for them in the [Debian package](http://packages.debian.org/stable/udev).)

If you want to give a meaningful name to an interface and you have `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, all you need to do is to edit that file and change `"eth0"` to `"ethLan"`. Run `udevadm trigger --sysname eth0` to rename the existing device after you've edited the file (I think this requires shutting down the interface). If you don't have that file, you can write the one-line matching yourself (the complicated scripts that Debian adds are only to do this automatically):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="01:23:45:67:89:ab", NAME="ethLan"
```

Comment: If you want a handy list of attributes usable in udev rules, you can try something like `udevadm info -a /sys/class/net/eth0`. (see [`udevadm(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/udevadm.8.html) for details)

Comment: The question clearly states to be for Wheezy, yet it might be worth noting that this answer is no longer valid for newer Debian and Ubuntu. Starting with [systemd 220-7](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2015/08/msg01083.html) interface naming needs to be done via other means.

Comment: @sampi My answer still applies to Debian jessie (the current stable release). Does it fail on stretch, or is it just recommending a deprecated method? Do you know which release of Ubuntu is the cutoff?

Comment: @Gilles I did not dig deep enough into the details in order to know whether it actually fails or merely is a recommended deprecation. It seems Ubuntu Wily and newer [use systemd higher than 220-7](http://packages.ubuntu.com/systemd).

Answer (score 7):

For people coming across this post via a search engine, like me:

In Debian stretch and newer, you can use systemd .link files to have udev rename the devices. See https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/udev/systemd.link.5.en.html for the manpage.

An example:

```
cat /etc/systemd/network/10-uplink0.link 
[Match]
MACAddress=00:0d:b9:49:8a:18

[Link]
Name=uplink0
```

Don’t forget to run `update-initramfs -u` afterwards to embed these updated config files into your initramfs, where they will be applied.

Comment: If the link files are present in a system with udev.rules.d which one will take precedence?

Answer (score 1):

There is a slightly simpler way to do that with a package named `ifrename`.  It has a separate (from `udev`) configuration file and you can use MAC addresses to identify interfaces.

It conflicts with `wireless-tools` however.

Comment: It should be noted that `ifrename` will conflict with `udev` if both are used to give interfaces persistent names.