# Configuring multiple static IP addresses for a disk image

Tags: ubuntu, debian, networking, networkmanager, ethernet

Using Ubuntu 10.04

I'm using Clonezilla to create and install a customized image. I'd like to be able to set up multiple static IP addresses. For example, I'd like the first interface to have the IP 10.0.0.1 and the second interface to have the IP 10.0.0.2

I have tried setting up two connections using NetworkManager, but can't associate a specific MAC address with them as these will be different for all target machines. Because of this, NetworkManager sets both adapters to the same IP address (10.0.0.1).

I clear the udev network rules before imaging, so all machines are guaranteed to have an eth0 interface. However some targets are going to use a USB NIC adapter for the second interface, so they are not guaranteed to have an eth1. That is, it's possible that different USB NIC adapters will be used, and Linux will assign each a new interface name.

Is there any way to assign the two IP addresses to the different adapters without the second having a fixed name using NetworkManager or /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: I think the easiest place is in the Udev configuration: define an alias for your Ethernet devices that doesn't depend on the hardware type. See [changing the names of network interfaces, debian wheezy](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28883) for inspiration.